# How to know default position of the element?

Tags: jquery

Suppose of the following html:

```
<main class="main">
   <div class="foo"></div>
</main>
```

`.foo` may be anywhere in the document not exactly as in the above html. So it may be even like this:

```
<header class="header">
   <div class="bar"></div>
   <div class="blah">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div></div>
   </div>
</header>
```

So, now I will shift the `.foo` element to the `footer`:

```
$('.foo').appendTo('.footer')
```

Now, after some time I want to rollback the `.foo` element to its default position and place the `.foo` there:

```
$('.foo').appendTo(????)
//Or,
$('.foo').insertAfter(????)
//Or,
$('.foo').insertBefore(????)
```

How should I play with this?

Comment: why dont you hide the original '.foo' element , clone it and use. Later when you need to roll back, delete the clone, and display the hidden one :)

Comment: cloning methods hamper many things on the element, that's why I don't want to use cloning method.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to hide the original object and to clone it or you want to keep only one instance of this element, you can add a dummy hidden element after it and then, just get the hidden element and append your DIV after

Answer (score 0):

You have modified the DOM using jQuery, so it is no longer in it's "default" location as it was when you loaded the page. One probably not great option is to cache a selector to it before you move it to the footer using a while loop and the `parent()` method. You could also clone the element and hide the original.

Another option is to leave a hidden element at the old location in the DOM.

```
$foo = $('.foo');
$foo.after('<span class="fooOriginal"></span>');
$foo.appendTo('.footer');

// revert
$foo.appendTo('.fooOriginal');
```

Comment: can you give me an example? Just only using parent() method won't fit for this requirement because this may be anywhere and how should I use that? appendTo, or insertAfter, or insertBefore??

Comment: you would have to loop until you got to the `<body>` or some other place you know the location. I think a better option is to clone it

Comment: That should be insertBefore not appendTo.